# Jquery data localization in laravel project

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, localization

Good Morning. I am new in laravel project and working in localization... Having date and time created by Javascript I can't translate months and week days, because date have been created with jquery,,, is there way to translate it in js file ?? Thanks in advice ...

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has functions to display dates in a certain locale.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString